# Aligning textviews with imageview in a gridlayout

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout, qgridlayout

I'm trying to align 5 textviews with an imageview. I've created a gridlayout with 2 columns and 5 rows. In column 0 are 5 textviews divided in 5 rows. In column 1 is an imageview that spans over the 5 rows. But I can't get my desired layout. See below the desired layout:

[image]

My code:

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridlayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titel_over_ons">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/intro"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/foto_over_ons"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:contentDescription="@string/dm_design_webdesign_moobiele_applicaties_en_grafische_vormgeving" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titel_dr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tekst_dr"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titel_service"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tekst_service"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


    </GridLayout>
```

Can someone help me with this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: You may have better luck with a relative layout where you can position views specifically next to or below other views. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Comment: Don't use a gridlayout, it does not respect spaces and weights. If you must, use the one from support v7. Use a TableLayout with proper spanning to achieve this easily

Comment: I've even tried to use Tablelayout but it doesn't support rowspan

Comment: if you use GridLayout you will have hard times everytime you add or remove textView, Here you dont need GridLayout, you need 2 LinearLayouts or Relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will show the TextViews divided equally :

(Remove the backgrounds, they are just for view proposes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#222" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#675" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#989" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#e34" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#e76" />




    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="#eae"
        />



</LinearLayout>]
```

[image: Imagem de como ficaria]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the span of element using one of this attributes:

```
android:layout_columnSpan="..."
android:layout_rowSpan="..."
```

In your case it will be

```
android:layout_columnSpan="5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for xml which is good to design this type of layouts:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:text="One"
        android:background="@android:color/white"            
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Two"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Three"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Four"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Five"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>        

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```